# Creating custom error message labels in html with Django framework

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display a list of fields within a form, with any field that is not properly validated or filled out (if required) to display at the top of the page. I have the following code in my html body:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <b>Incorrect fields to correct:</b>
    <ul>
{% for error in form.errors %}
    <li>{{ error }}</li>
{% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

and this loops through all of my fields that have errors in it. However, the data that is displayed from

```
{{ error }}
```

are my variable names. Can I change my output so that I can display different output replacing my variables names?

---

My variables are within this class:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core import validators

class InformationForm(forms.Form):
    #...
    full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=130)
    #rest of fields follow...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form you can define custom error messages.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages

Something along the lines of:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    my_field=forms.CharField(... error_messages={'required': 'My Field',})
```

EDIT: 
Try the following:

```
{% for field in form%}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I do not use a ModelForm, I use form.Form (edited question with more code)

Comment: @JimRilye. karhikr is right. A form.Form field can take the parameter `error_messages={}` as well. So just add that parameter to `full_name`

Comment: @dar2162, the fix does change the error text, but I am asking if I can change my label within my {% for loop %}

Comment: @dar2162, no. The label in my for loop prints out my variable name

Comment: @JimRilye try what I've added above